# How can I run a variable containing shell commands and pipes?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, eval

In **Bash** I need to run a *variable* containing *commands*, and then assign the output to another variable. The problem is there are several commands and there are some pipes or something like that.

Below is a sample:

```
snmpwalk -Ov -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.6574.1.2.0 | awk "{print $2}"
```

And:

```
upsc ups | grep input.voltage: | cut -d" " -f2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `eval`. But be wary that `eval` is evil when string is not sanitized. Ever heard of [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/)?

Comment: The jokers in your woodpile are the `awk` program and the `-d" "` argument to `cut`, because they contain spaces which make plain string handling into a complete pain.  In principle, `eval "${array[@]}"` will then 'work', but you have to be so careful it is unbearable (which is why this isn't an answer). Using `array=(snmpwalk -Ov -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.6574.1.2.0 '|' awk "'{print \$2}'")` allows you to use `eval "${array[$@]}"`, but note the double quotes around single quotes and the escaped dollar; they don't lend themselves to easy handling.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ Often, your best bet is to get the content into a file and then execute the file.  At least that is readily debuggable.

Comment: Yes, I've got the idea to write the variable content into file and execute it right after make this post. Did not try it yet. It doesn't look like pure solution but should do the work... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

```
cmd='upsc ups | grep input.voltage: | cut -d" " -f2'
result=`echo "$cmd" | bash`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the stdout of any command or pipeline to a variable like this:

```
result=$(upsc ups | grep input.voltage: | cut -d" " -f2)
```

Comment: I think you've missed what the question is asking about.